# iptables - route traffic back to origin GRE interface

Tags: linux, iptables, gre

I'm struggling with iptables and packet marking.I have set up a system with 3 interfaces

eno1: 192.168.0.100
gre1: 10.0.0.2
gre2: 10.0.0.6

and there is a local daemon running on eno1 port 1111 (nc -l -p 1111 -s 192.168.0.100). The incoming traffic from gre1 and gre2 shall be forwarded to eno1:1111 and the response shall go back to the corresponding gre-interface. I only found a solution that sends back the traffic to one interface:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i gre1 --destination X.X.X.X -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.35.100:1111
ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.0.0.1 dev gre1 table GRE
iptables -A OUTPUT -o eno1 -t mangle -p tcp --sport 1111 -j MARK --set-mark 1
ip rule add fwmark 1 table GRE
```

I have tried different solutions from certain threads using CONNMARK but without any success. Does anyone have an idea how to get it working for both interfaces?

Edit: 2023-12-08 for clarification
What I want to achieve (and what my current solution realizes for one tunnel) is that the packet which is contained in the GRE-packet is answered by my local daemon as if it was the requested server. To give an example: The packet which is contained in the GRE-packet coming from gre1 has the destination ip x.x.x.x and the source ip y.y.y.y. This packet is forwarded to my local daemon and the reply-packet has source ip x.x.x.x. and destination ip y.y.y.y. And this packet shall use the gre tunnel it came from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you doing DNAT and mangle with a gre tunnel?

The point of a gre tunnel, is to get through the firewall so you can then use standard routing.

What Subnet are you using for 10.0.0.6 and 10.0.0.2?

I am assuming they are /30 address, so the remote end of 10.0.0.2 is 10.0.0.1 and the remote end of 10.0.0.6 is 10.0.0.5?

Lets assume the remote subnet at the end of the .2 tunnel is 192.168.2.0/24 and at the end of .6 is 192.168.6.0/24.

Then you add the routes of:

```
ip route add 192.168.2.0/24 dev gre1
ip route add 192.168.6.0/24 dev gre2
```

enable forwarding via

```
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.gre1.forwarding=1
sysctl net.ipv4.conf.gre2.forwarding=1
```

no need to do any nat routing locally on the machine.

If you want to restrict it to only the 1111 port, then a simple inbound rules would work.

```
iptables -I INPUT -i gre+ -j DROP
iptables -I INPUT -i gre+ -p tcp --sport 1111 -j ACCEPT
```

I use the -I for the rules, to add them to the top of your rules, and that is why DROP is first and the allow second.  Make sure this is not going to block your current connection.

If you want other endpoints on the remote ends to be able to reach the local daemon, then add the route to 192.168.0.0/24 to go the server with the gre interface.  Enable forwarding on the local network interface of that server.

All done, no need for NAT, gre tunnels are there to remove the need for nat.  Otherwise, you can just use the external IP address of the site, and forward port 1111 to the local server, and use NAT that way.  Often for large companies, they need a port to go to numerous endpoints, and that is where gre is used.

Based on the extra info, the issue is you do not know the source IP's or the subnets they are coming from, and you need it to return the same path as it came from?  Have you looked at nginx as a proxy in that case?  If you want to use iptables then you will need something like:

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i gre+ -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.35.100:1111  *to change the detination to the endpoint you want.
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -o eno1 -d 192.168.35.100 -p tcp --dport 1111 -j MASQUERADE
```

let iptables do its magic in the background and keep track of the sessions, and the return path of the packet.

As we do not modify the source IP address in the PREROUTING table, then MASQUERADE will subsitute the source to be the servers IP, and will do the reverse when it comes back.

Alternatively, if you have access to the server at the source of the gre tunnel, you could do NAT there, therefore you know if the source is 10.0.0.1 it goes to gre1 and if it is 10.0.0.5 then it is gre2, and the rules.  SImple SNAT and routing would handle the return path.

Comment: Dear Luke many thanks for your quick replay. Unfortunately it is more complicated. What I want to achieve and what my current solution realizes for one tunnel is that the packet which is contained in the GRE-packet is answered by my local daemon as if it was the requested server. 

To give an example: The packet which is contained in the GRE-packet coming from gre1 has the destination ip x.x.x.x  and the source ip y.y.y.y. This packet is forwarded to my local daemon and the reply-packet has source ip x.x.x.x. and destination ip y.y.y.y. And this packet shall use the gre tunnel it came from.

Comment: I dont know the source ips contained in the gre-packets beforehand, so I can't define network specific routes. I tried to mark the incoming packets from gre1 and gre2, but the reply packets from netcat don't have any mark. So i was wondering if I could use iptables to keep track of the incoming packets and to make sure that the replies use the same way they came from. I tried CONNTRACK but I couldn't get it to work :-( My colleagues say that iptables can't realize what I want, but I am not sure if I am using it the right way.

Comment: Do you have access to root at the sourcepoints of the gre tunnels? If you use nat at the source, then you can use basic route tables to ensure it uses the correct gre tunnel.  If you do not have access, SNAT should work, in your post routing in iptables, use --SNAT --to-source, and the ip of the gre.  iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -i gre1 xxxxxx -j SNAT --to-source <ip of gre1>

Comment: I have no root-access to the sourcepoints of the tunnel. So I tried:
`iptables -t nat -I POSTROUTING -o gre1 -j SNAT --to-source 10.0.0.2` but it didn't work for me. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to mark packets that come from GRE tunnels to mark their origin. An example:

```
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i gre0 -j MARK --mark 0x1
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i gre1 -j MARK --mark 0x2
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -j CONNMARK --save-mark
```

First rule restores the mark from connection tracking to the IP packet.

The second and third rule mark packets from `gre0`/`gre1` with different marks.

Third rule saves the packet mark to a connection mark.

With these rules, all packets relating to a single flow should have a mark that tells which interface the flow is associated with.

Comment: Dear Tero, thanks for your reply. I tried:
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j CONNMARK --restore-mark
iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i gre1 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1
iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -j CONNMARK --save-mark
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i gre1 --destination X.X.X.X -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.100:1001
ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.0.0.1 dev gre1 table GRE
ip rule add fwmark 0x1 table GRE

but it doesn't work. Am I missing something?

Comment: with markup:`iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -j CONNMARK --restore-mark` <br/>  `iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i gre1 -j MARK --set-mark 0x1`<br/>  `iptables -t mangle -A POSTROUTING -j CONNMARK --save-mark`<br/> ` iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -i gre1 --destination X.X.X.X -p tcp --dport 80 -j DNAT --to 192.168.0.100:1001`<br/>  `ip route add 0.0.0.0/1 via 10.0.0.1 dev gre1 table GRE` <br/> `ip rule add fwmark 0x1 table GRE`

Comment: Why do you route `0.0.0.0/1` via the gateway? That matches half of the IPv4 address space (0.0.0.0 - 127.255.255.255).

Comment: To be honest, I just took this from a gre-tutorial and did no fine tuning yet. It should be `0.0.0.0/0` finally.

Comment: So, does your destination match the route that you are using?

Comment: Yes, in my case it matches. But I have changed it now.

Comment: I have got it working! :-) Thank you very much. This thread helped me: https://serverfault.com/questions/1107846/how-to-route-a-reply-packet-to-the-device-it-coming-from

Answer (score 0):

mangle and connmark was the solution:

`iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -i gre1 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j MARK --set-mark 1`
`iptables -t mangle -A PREROUTING -m mark --mark 1 -j CONNMARK --save-mark`

`iptables -t mangle -A OUTPUT -j CONNMARK --restore-mark`